# Проблема с подключением к FTP-серверу через прокси

Tags: ftp, delphi, proxy

Доброго времени суток. У меня появилась следующая проблема: ниже описан код, которым я пытаюсь подключиться к фтп серверу. Я нахожусь в офисе, выход в интернет осуществляется через прокси UserGate. И что-то не получается у меня пробиться через проксю, вылетают ошибки:

```
 1. Project IP.exe raised exception class EIdSocketError with message 'Socket Error
    # 10061 Connection refused.'.
 2. Project IP.exe raised exception class EIdSocketError with message 'Socket Error
    # 10054 Connection reset by peer.'.  - если не указываю тип прокси
```

С этим компонентом работаю впервые, так что не судите строго. Возможно есть еще какой-то компонент для этих целей, работающий с Delphi XE2? 
Прошу помочь, товарищи :)

```
   IdFtp1.Host     := 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
   IdFtp1.Username := 'xxx';
   IdFtp1.Password := 'xxx';
   IdFtp1.ProxySettings.UserName:= '';
   IdFtp1.ProxySettings.Password:= '';
   IdFtp1.ProxySettings.ProxyType:= fpcmUserSite;
   IdFtp1.ProxySettings.Host:= '192.168.2.1';
   IdFtp1.ProxySettings.Port:= 5456;
   IdFTP1.Passive := True;
   IdFtp1.Connect;
```

Comment: Причем для других программ (например, тотал коммандер) необязательно указывать логин и пароль для прохождения прокси, достаточно только выбрать сам прокси. Сервер всех пропускает без проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче Indy FTP не дружит с HTTP proxy - несовместимость протоколов, все дела...
У других библиотек (которые я посмотрел) нельзя настраивать proxy для FTP элементов.
И я пришел к выводу, что, чтобы чем-то подобным заниматься, надо иметь черный пояс по программированию.

Comment: Я не знаю, кто такой Indy FTP, но реализация простенького некеширующего ftp-proxy - это не чёрный пояс, а несложная РГР (расчётно-графическая работа).